# How to export PDF with inverted background and text colors

Tags: pdf, latex

How do you export a `PDF` file with *inverted* **background and text colors** in LaTex?

Comment: Export from what? Which programming language do you use? Which PDF library? What have you tried?

Comment: Want to do it from LaTex

Comment: You are aware that your question as is does not show that? You don't even mention LaTeX in it or its tags. Please consider updating your question to express what you are looking for.